# Custom posts password protect

Tags: php, functions

my site is highly based on clients and we want to have very strong password protection for a certain custom type post.

We have a custom type post named "something" and here is it's declaration:

```
$args = array (
            'label' => 'Something',
            'singular_label' => 'Something',
            'public' => false,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => "something"),
            'query_var' => false,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-chart-area',
            'supports' => array('title')
    );
```

I want to make sure anything that's under slug "something" is password protected and if a post with type "something" has a password set, then it asks users to enter the password.

One problem that I'm encountering with this custom post type declaration is, it doesn't even ask users to enter a password even if password is set.

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? What worked and what didn't work? What specific problems are you facing? You will need to go into more detail to get any useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `post_password_required()` function to check if the post is protected.

```
<?php
global $post;

$p = $post; // can be post object.
// $p = $post->ID; // also can be post ID.

$this_post_type = get_post_type( $p );

if ( 'my_custom_post_type' === $this_post_type ) { // check the post type.

    if ( ! post_password_required( $p ) ) {
        // unprotected post loop here.
    } else {
        // protected post, show the password form.
        echo get_the_password_form( $p );
    }
}
```

If you use a custom template for this post type you can skip post type check.

However, the code above was not tested.